# Passing the object of ActiveX control on a worksheet to sub or function

Tags: excel, vba

I have a couple ActiveX Textboxes on a worksheet. I also have a sub that needs to receive the textbox "Object" so that it can work with the properties, i.e. value, position, enabled. Every time I try to pass the textbox object it gets passed as the textbox "Value" so I get a "Type Mismatch" or "Object variable or With block" error. I have tried so many variation my head is spinning.

Tried:

```
Private Sub CBDate1_Click()

    Dim InputCtl As OLEObject
    Set InputCtl = TBStartDate
    
    Call SF_DatePick.DatePickinCtl(InputCtl)

End Sub
```

Tried:

```
Private Sub CBDate1_Click()
    
    Dim InputCtl As OLEObject
    Set InputCtl = TBStartDate
    
    SF_DatePick.DatePickinCtl InputCtl

End Sub
```

Tried:

```
Private Sub CBDate1_Click()
    
    Dim InputCtl As Object
    
    Call SF_DatePick.DatePickinCtl(InputCtl)

End Sub
```

Tried:

```
Private Sub CBDate1_Click()
    
    Dim InputCtl As Object
    
    SF_DatePick.DatePickinCtl InputCtl

End Sub
```

And a hundred others.

Here is the receiving code in the Sub

```
Public Sub DatePickinCtl(InputCtl As Control, _
                         Optional FormatTxT As String = "Short Date", _
                         Optional Language As String = "", _
                         Optional HolidayLocation As String = "", _
                         Optional ThreeMonthFlag As Boolean = False)
    Dim TVar As Variant, DOut As Variant
    TVar = InputCtl.Value
```

I have also tried dimming as textbox. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is you use `InputCtl as Object`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get a type mismatch as a result of passing a variable to a function or sub-procedure by reference it means that the datatype of the argument passed does not match the datatype of the parameter.  While I'm not sure what the precise datatype should be, you should be able to get by with a general datatype so try defining the InputCtrl parameter as Object or Variant as follows:

```
Public Sub DatePickinCtl(InputCtl As Object, _
                     Optional FormatTxT As String = "Short Date", _
                     Optional Language As String = "", _
                     Optional HolidayLocation As String = "", _
                     Optional ThreeMonthFlag As Boolean = False)
```

or

```
Public Sub DatePickinCtl(InputCtl As Variant, _
                     Optional FormatTxT As String = "Short Date", _
                     Optional Language As String = "", _
                     Optional HolidayLocation As String = "", _
                     Optional ThreeMonthFlag As Boolean = False)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, changed it to object and it works like a charm now. I was using this sub with a user form previously and it never clicked about sheets have objects not controls.

Comment: Glad it helped.  I think that the comment DS_London made while I was writing this answer is getting at the same thing, it might be nice to upvote that comment

Comment: De Nada! A VBA `Object` is the root of all VBA classes. So if you are not sure of the exact type, you can pass as Object. Technically this means that the type supports the IDispatch interface which means it can be queried at run-time for the methods and properties it supports ... which is what happens here. The variable you are passing may be a TextBox type, but it can always be viewed as an `Object`. VBA can then check at run-time that this object supports the `Value` property.

Comment: As an aside, this is why using `Variant` also works: the variant's type is set as `vbObject` so VBA knows how to handle it.

Comment: FWIW, it can be specifically declared as `Excel.OLEObject`.